# How can one add a yum repository in AWS::CloudFormation::Init

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to install docker in a Centos instance using cloudformation and the blocks of `AWS::CloudFormation::Init`

One of the installation [steps](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/scratchpads2/wiki/Install-Docker-and-Docker-Compose-(Centos-7)) is to add a certain repository to yum by running:

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

How can I enable that repository in a cloudformation template. Ideally, I would like to use a single config block if that's possible.

This is what I got so far

```
Resources:
  ec2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          packages:
            yum:
              yum-utils: []
              device-mapper-persistent-data: []
              lvm2: []
    Properties:
      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that by adding a `commands` block:

```
Resources:
  ec2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          config:
            - yum_config_manager
            - yum_packages
        yum_config_manager:
          commands:
            yum_config_manager:
              command: yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
        yum_packages:
          packages:
            yum:
              yum-utils: []
              device-mapper-persistent-data: []
              lvm2: []
```

And in your `UserData` you will have:

```
cfn-init -c config -s ${AWS::StackId} --resource ec2 --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Further explanation:

- Note that the `commands` and `packages` blocks have each been wrapped in a `configSet`.
- Note also that the `-c config` tells `cfn-init` which of the `configSets` you want to run.

After it boots up you should be able to inspect successful operation by looking in `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log`.

More info in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) especially the sections on [configSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-configsets) and [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-commands).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! AFAIK, if I wanted to install the package included in that repository I would have to add that in the packages block, isn't it? But packages get interpreted before the commands block based on aws blocks. Is there a way to achieve that without using configSets?

Comment: @JaviOverflow, my bad. I had tested on an EC2 instance that already had those packages installed, so I didn't notice the ordering problem. It's fixed in my update.

Comment: @JaviOverflow , I missed the last part of your question here, “...without using configSets”. As far as I understand it, the whole point of configSets is to control the ordering (and provide groups of configs etc). So I don’t think there’s any other way, and I can’t see any disadvantages of using configSets.